# Como utilizar uma mascara em uma textbox dinamica?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

Estou precisando implementar uma máscara (valor) em n campos TextBox (definidas por n periodos x n contratos) dentro de uma grid, onde elas são geradas dinamicamentes. Utilizo o jQuery para as textboxes estáticas (AutoNumeric). Porém não sei como referencia-las dinamicamente, uma vez que preciso do ClientID para que o autonumeric funcione.

Trecho do script que utilizo o autoNumeric em uma TextBox Estática: (.aspx)

```
$("#<%=txtValor.ClientID%>").autoNumeric({ aSep: '.', aDec: ',' });
```

Método no code-behind em que gero uma textbox dinâmica (.cs):

```
private TextBox geraTextBox(string periodo, string linha)
    {
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.ID = periodo + "_" + linha;
        textBox.Width = 50;
        textBox.AutoPostBack = true;
        textBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtBoxes_TextChanged);
        textBox.ReadOnly = false;
        return textBox;
    }
```

Obs: Peço perdão por qualquer erro de sintaxe/utlização do Stack Overflow. É a primeira vez que faço uma pergunta.

Comment: A forma mais correta, seria você criar um novo controle e implementar a interface `IScriptControl`. De uma olhada neste [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/bb386450(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Está em VB, mas no geral é a mesma coisa. Você pode também adicionar um atributo no textbox, que implemente o método load do javascript.

Comment: vou utilizar a primeira estratégia e depois passo o resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei deixando o `IScriptControl` de lado, pois com a quantidade de TextBoxes que iria manusear, implicaria em um retorno muito demorado. Utilizei a segunda opção, em JavaScript. Dentro do `RowDataBound` adicionei um atributo que implementava a máscara. Passei o clientID por parametro, e o javascript fez o resto. Segue abaixo a solução:

Server-Side (.cs):

```
protected void gdvCriarProjeto_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    (...)
    var txt = e.Row.FindControl(periodo + "_" + linha) as TextBox;
    txt.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:Moeda(\"" + txt.ClientID + "\")");
    (...)
}
```

Client-Side (.aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Moeda(id_textbox) {
        var campo = document.getElementById(id_textbox);
        $(campo).autoNumeric({ aSep: '.', aDec: ',' });      
    }
</script>
```